# How can I add a linked text to email with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I'm trying to add a linked text to a JavaScript generated email such as:
***Hi, here is some text that if you'll click on, will bring you to some web page***

I don't care much about the format (Underline or bold etc.).

I found some threads regarding using HTML, but also found that it is not always working (depends on default mail).

Is there any way I can do it using my ***mailto:*** value?

Comment: You should add the code that generates the email.

Comment: I think the problem is with the encoding of the html, if you want to add the link as html.

Answer (score 0):

You can add only a plain text into mailto's body:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=SUBJECT&cc=test@example.com&body=BODY">SEND</a>
```

> The "body" should contain the content for the first text/plain body
> part of the message. The mailto URL is primarily intended for
> generation of short text messages that are actually the content of
> automatic processing (such as "subscribe" messages for mailing lists),
> not general MIME bodies [[source]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368)